# What's wrong with this dynamic layout? [Android]

Tags: android, xml, dynamic

I need to create dynamically LinearLayout which represent this xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ddd"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="1dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="26dp"
        android:paddingTop="26dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView04"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="#eee" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="Name of event"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="Group of this event"
                android:textColor="#aaa"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the problem is that I wrote some code but I have no idea why after debugging my application the only thing which I see is name of event.

Here's the code:

```
public class Event extends LinearLayout{

    private LinearLayout globalContener;
    private LinearLayout contener;
    private LinearLayout avatarBox;
    private LinearLayout contentBox;

    private TextView eventName;
    private TextView eventGroup;

    private ImageView avatar;

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams globalContenerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams contenerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams avatarBoxParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(160, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams contentBoxParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams eventNameParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams eventGroupParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams avatarParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(48, 48);

    public Event(Context context){
        super(context);

        // Design of global contener
        globalContenerParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 32);

        globalContener = new LinearLayout(context);
        globalContener.setBackgroundColor(0xDDDDDD);
        globalContener.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        globalContener.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        globalContener.setLayoutParams(globalContenerParams);

        // Design of contener
        contener = new LinearLayout(context);
        contener.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
        contener.setPadding(0, 26, 0, 26);
        contener.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        contener.setLayoutParams(contenerParams);

        // Design of avatar box
        avatarBox = new LinearLayout(context);
        avatarBox.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
        avatarBox.setLayoutParams(avatarBoxParams);

        // Design of contet box
        contentBox = new LinearLayout(context);
        contentBox.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        contentBox.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
        contentBox.setLayoutParams(contentBoxParams);

        // Design of avatar
        avatarParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        avatarParams.setMargins(32, 4, 0, 0);

        avatar = new ImageView(context);
        avatar.setBackgroundDrawable(Const.avatarImg);
        avatar.setLayoutParams(avatarParams);

        // Design of event name
        eventNameParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

        eventName = new TextView(context);
        eventName.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        eventName.setPadding(16, 0, 0, 4);
        eventName.setTextSize(22);
        eventName.setText("Sprawdzian z języka polskiego");
        eventName.setLayoutParams(eventNameParams);

        // Design of event group
        eventGroup = new TextView(context);
        eventGroup.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        eventGroup.setPadding(16, 0, 0, 0);
        eventGroup.setTextSize(16);
        eventGroup.setTextColor(0xAAAAAA);
        eventGroup.setText("4ia Technikum Łączności w Krakowie");
        eventGroup.setLayoutParams(eventGroupParams);

        // Packing boxes
        avatarBox.addView(avatar);

        contentBox.addView(eventGroup);
        contentBox.addView(eventName);

        contener.addView(avatarBox);
        contener.addView(contentBox);

        globalContener.addView(contener);

        // Adding to view
        addView(globalContener);
    }
}
```

Is anyone here who can help me with this?

Comment: Just use [this](http://www.xmltojava.com/)

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to create it dynamically in code rather than use the layout file you already have?

Comment: I need to have n of this events boxes, because I don't now how many events user have.

Comment: That is no reason to do it dynamically, and it sounds to me that you want an adapter based view, like recycler view. Probably if you better explain what you trying to achieve, someone can explain you the correct approach. Because this is not a good approach for anything on android.

Comment: I realize that it's rather not good way to create something in android but I'm new in it and easier for me is to build sth simillary to html. 

Maybe exits any method to create dynamically n objects but using xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

set your main LinearLayout Orientation to Vertical
and then
set contentBoxParams weight to 1f

```
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams contentBoxParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);
```

then
put this

```
contentBox.addView(eventName);
```

before this

```
contentBox.addView(eventGroup);
```

and then replace all the 
`0xFFFFFF` with `0xFFFFFFFF`

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it's vertical :(

Here is a result when I create this using xml:

http://oi59.tinypic.com/az054.jpg

And here when it's dynamically:

http://oi58.tinypic.com/2uo16i1.jpg

Comment: set contentBoxParams weight to 1f

Comment: private LinearLayout.LayoutParams contentBoxParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);

Comment: It's little bit better, but still it's not exactly the same box.

Comment: show me the deference so maybe i can figure out what is missing

Comment: First : 
put this `contentBox.addView(eventName);` before this
`contentBox.addView(eventGroup);`

Comment: and then replace all the `0xFFFFFF` with `0xFFFFFFFF`

Comment: Okey! It's working :) 

I changed `0xFFFFFF` to `0xFFFFFFFF` and `0xDDDDDD` to `0xFFDDDDDD` and `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to `LayoutParams` and it is workig :) 

**Thanks!** :)

Comment: your welcome FYI this happened cuz 0xFFFFFF is actually 0x00FFFFFF
so it's transparent white

Comment: Yup, I forgot about it :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SiKing how about now ?